# How to find reason my Blazor app crashed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

i'm new in Blazor developing and made small project that worked well but before couple of days i made something and now my multiple project app with server, client and api when runs they are start loading but after 1-2 seconds api and server quit and only client app stay loading. I don't know where to look for a problem to solve it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC0ad.jpg)

Comment: Any hints in the event viewer?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that a "small project that worked well" is running correctly in non-debug mode and is crashing with Debug mode enabled.   However, without any detail there is no way to answer this question.   What errors are you seeing in the output?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new bug now in Blazor.

Press CTRL+Q, search for 'Breakpoints' delete every breakpoint, rebuild and solution and I recommend to update the VS in installer.

For me this was the problem. I hope it solves your too.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is from debugger  and after little searching i updated my Vs 2022 to last version. Now I tried your advice but the problem is same. Can run app without debugger, but with breakpoint program crash. I also cleaned VS cashe in AppData